# resolvconf package create corrupt /etc/resolv.conf file

Tags: debian, dns, resolv.conf, nano, resolvconf

I'm having a weird issue under debian 11 with resolvconf package.

No matter what kind of configuration I throw in, the /etc/resolv.conf file created by resolvconf service is kinda corrupt.

Dig says:

```
dig: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed
```

If I use an editor like nano to add just a space or newline or even nothing like overwriting the file from nano to /etc/resolv.conf dig goes back reading the file again, the same goes with the os that is able to perform the dns lookups otherwise not.

To me the syntax is ok, the actual content is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.2.1
```

I have a configured bind server on the machine that works properly and the actual configuration works but ONLY if I read it from nano and re-save it in place.

Regarding the file itself I tought maybe could be a permission difference between what does resolvconf daemon and what nano does.

This is before nano edit:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 10 19:24 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

This is after nano edit:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 10 19:24 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

I also made a cp of the first one and swapped, the original one doesn't work, the new one yes.

The files compared are identically...

I have no idea what is happening :(

Comment: can you use the `-L` option (dereference symlinks) when listing before and after? `ls -lL /etc/resolv.conf`. That's to see the rights of the actual target file, not of the symlink. Having the file not readable for a normal user could trigger your error (for a normal user).

Comment: thanks I found I had an issue with the permissions but another thing is the one in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared the files visually, and nothing was different. However in just one point aside the permission error @A.B suggested me I found also that there was a line with `\r\n` instead of `\n` in my head file.

Editing and saving the file with nano fixed automatically the newline error but with the `diff` tool everything was more clear.

Do not trust visual comparison use **diff**! :D